# Let bakers pass their own entropy to generate random numbers on chain

Tags: smart-contracts

Might be a stupid question, but would it be possible to let each bakers emmit a random number each time a block is baked, then aggregate those numbers, make a hash from the result, and store it in the block?

That would provide a way to get an unpredictable random number on-chain for each blocks?

I still struggle to get a random number for NFT random generation

Comment: If the baker chooses it, it is not unpredictable for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how randomness for PoS is generated. That plus a VDF. The issue with this scheme is that, while it's quite robust, producing entropy takes quite a long time.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, I was just watching your TezDev Paris 2022 video this afternoon, I strongly believe in on chain gaming on Tezos but can't wrap my head around an efficient way to use randomization, which is an essential part of game development

Comment: Ask another question then, namely, "how to get randomness for my game" and I'll happily answer that too :-)

Comment: Thanks :) https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/random-number-on-chain?rq=1