# Details on VDF for randomization

Tags: smart-contracts

so i was going through this article,
https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/verifiable-delay-functions.html

the more i read it, the more i got confused, Is there a easy way we can achieve this through the contract to achieve a random number? Or is this just for bakers?

Answer (score 0):

The Verifiable Delay Functions (VDF) mentioned in the article you linked to are referring to the protocol's underlying random number generation, used for consensus, so is not something you can use in a Smart Contract.

You may be interested in the following posts, which deal with RNGs in smart contracts:

- [Random Numbers Generation](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4570/random-numbers-generation)
- [Random number on-chain](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/random-number-on-chain)

There is also a [good article](https://opentezos.com/smart-contracts/avoiding-flaws/#7-using-unreliable-sources-of-randomness) dealing with random number generation in Tezos smart contracts.