# Will smart rollups allow to produce random numbers on chain?

Tags: random, randomness

Will smart rollups or future Tezos upgrades allow to produce random numbers on chain?
Or do we will still need to use the [oracle solution or commit/reveal scheme?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/random-number-on-chain?rq=1)

(There's a need for random number generation in almost any on-chain game I can think of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart Rollups are fully deterministic: their behavior only depends on the inputs settled by the L1.

Therefore there is no more non-determinism than the one you can get from the L1.

Comment: Thanks! It's hard to imagine interesting fully on-chain games without randomness, I will check Etherlink oracles